# php POST data retrieving issue

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I am retrieveing data from $_GET on page linked by:

```
<a class="send" href="<?php echo sendData.php?user=somebody&password=any; ?>">Send POST info</a>
```

locally using XAMPP with

```
            <?php
                $user = urlencode($_GET['user']);
                $password = urlencode($_GET['password']);
                echo '<strong>user: </strong>'.$user.' <strong>password: </strong>'.$password;                
            ?>
```

and it works fine, however when encoding

```
        <?php
            $url=rawurlencode('sendData.php');
            $url .= urlencode('?user=somebody&password=any');
        ?>
        <a class="send" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">

             Send POST info
        </a>
```

The linked page access is forbidden

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
18.10.2011 ã. 23:00:31 ÷.
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Any ideas what is messing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't encode the entire query-string.
In your code, you're converting the "?" and "&" and "=".

Encode the values individually, and concatenate the values.

So

```
$query = "?user=" . urlencode($user) . "&password=" . urlencode($password);
```

Ultimately, that's also going to allow you to sanitize them, as well.

Comment: Aye, if you view source, you'll see `<a class="send" href="sendData.php%3Fuser%3Dsomebody%26password%3Dany">` in your file, because you're encoding things you don't need to, as Norguard says.  Also, once you get the response, there's no need to `urlencode($_GET['user'])`. If you're encoding it for output, you could use something like `htmlspecialchars($_GET['user'])` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
        $url= 'sendData.php?';
        $url .= rawurlencode('user=somebody&password=any');
    ?>
```

Only need to encode the query string.